# Client and auth server

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a client, which connects to an auth server and checks to see if the username and password entered in the client is valid then if it is, the client downloads a .dll to the users machine.

My question is, what is the best and most secure way to go about doing this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific authentication protocol in mind?  There are multiple security issues involved, including *loading a DLL downloaded from somewhere*.  You might want to clarify what security issues you want to address: avoiding the transfer of credentials, safely storing passwords, run-time execution of untrusted code...

Comment: Im trying to avoid a malicious user trying to download the dll without permission from the server

Comment: What options have you considered?  A simple web page with a username & password form that validates against a database of known users isn't enough?  Just make sure you protect against SQL injection and serve everything over HTTPS to avoid eavesdropping of the password (and the protected file).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Send username and password in hashed form, on server also store hashes
2) When downloading .dll make sure it is signed, and signature is checked (use Verisign signature if you have one, or just do something based on CryptoAPI

2nd point assumes you don't need to hide contents of dll from sniffer, just need to make sure it is not modified